# Where does a helper function go in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Given a helper function:

```
def reset_defaults(func):
    func.__defaults__ = ({},)
```

Which is used:

```
import pytest
from src.DYNAMIC_PROGRAMMING.can_sum.can_sum import can_sum
from tests.conftest import reset_defaults

...

@pytest.mark.parametrize("target, numbers, sum_possible", test_cases, ids=ids)
def test_can_sum(target, numbers, sum_possible):
    reset_defaults(can_sum)
    assert can_sum(target, numbers) == sum_possible
```

Is conftest file the right place to keep that helper function? Could it be organised better (by using a fixture for instance)?

Comment: That's a very subjective question! It can go anywhere you want, as long as it's visible at the right place. It's up to you to structure the code in the way you prefer. This solution seems just fine to me.

Comment: Thanks @joanis, do realise this is subjective. I use Python and Pytest only non-commercially, but still would like to pick up some good practices.